# microsoft access package and sign not working

Tags: ms-access, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I have created a certificate request for code signing purposes. The sys admins told me they have never given one before and told me they need to set up local windows certificate issuing to hand out certificates for code signing purposes. They have sent me a certificate base 64 encoded once it is enabled. I imported cert into my pc and tried to sign the microsoft access. Microsoft access claims the digital signature is not valid.

When I look at the signature, it looks valid. Is there anyway I can debug why the cert is no good for code signing purposes ? Thanks.

Comment: What about providing the certificate (not the private key! ) to allow people here to analyze your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was dumb but here's what happened. When I went through the certmgr, it did not let me request a certificate through the AD policy. I had to create a request using the custom request. What I did not realize is that, I was issuing the command from another computer and sending the request and then importing the certificate from another computer.

Basically I did not have a private key on the other computer to sign the certificate, the certificate looked ok but the prompt that says "you have a private key ..." was not there. When I went in and imported the certificate, on the same computer that I have created the request from, the private key was found and I was able to sign it. That was stupid but you think, I would get a more descriptive warning.

Of course now that I have signed my access 2007 package, I figured out it, it still gives me a warning about macros and asks me to still enable.. My understanding was that signing your package will let others to run the content without running into trust center issues... Fudge....

Comment: The others running your content will probably need to add the CA cert or your cert to their trusted certificates.

Comment: The CA cert is automatically added by the deployment team to everyone on the domain. It is windows local domain CA cert. Problem was my stupidity.